# Convert timestamp to a readable date during query

Tags: sql, mysql

How can I tell MySQL to format a timestamp as a readable date before outputting a query result in a MySQL client/console?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) like this:

```
SELECT
  FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp_field) AS formatted_date
FROM
  tablename;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(column_name, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM tablename
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

You can also use TIME_FORMAT

Comment: While doing a SELECT *, is it also possible to convert only one of the fields?