# How to convert timestamp to datetime in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How to convert `1300464000` to `2011-03-18 16:00:00` in MySQL?

Comment: Please search for existing questions/answers before you post a new question - this topic has already been covered in some detail.

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation already? It's all there: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert timestamp to a readable date during query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978939/convert-timestamp-to-a-readable-date-during-query)

Answer (score 237, accepted):

Use the [**`FROM_UNIXTIME()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function in MySQL

Remember that if you are using a framework that stores it in milliseconds (for example Java's timestamp) you have **to divide by 1000** to obtain the right Unix time in seconds.

Comment: `SELECT from_unixtime( TIMESTAMP(  "2011-12-01",  "22:01:23.048" ) )` doesn't work. why? using v5.6

Comment: @JanusTroelsen `SELECT from_unixtime( unix_timestamp(TIMESTAMP(  "2011-12-01",  "22:01:23.048" ) ) )` works. `TIMESTAMP()` does not return an integer value.

Comment: Just because I've done this and been confused at the output: MySQL stores Unix time in seconds, whereas a lot of other frameworks store it in milliseconds (i.e. Java's timestamp). So just remember to divide by 1000 if you're using this function on data coming from somewhere that uses millis for Unix time.

Answer (score 81):

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`orderdate`), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as "Date" FROM `orders`
```

This is the ultimate solution if the given date is in encoded format like `1300464000`

Comment: Thanks for this. To include the time:

`DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(\`orderdate\`), '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') as "Date" FROM \`orders\` `

Comment: I'm pretty sure DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`orderdate`), '%Y-%m-%d') as "Date" FROM `orders` would be the ultimate solution :D

Answer (score 17):

To answer Janus Troelsen comment

Use [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) instead of [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp)

```
SELECT from_unixtime( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(  "2011-12-01 22:01:23.048" ) )
```

The TIMESTAMP function returns a Date or a DateTime and not a timestamp, while UNIX_TIMESTAMP returns a unix timestamp

Comment: seems clear to compare a unix time from a unix time. I use SELECT (CAST(DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)), '%Y-%m-%d') as DATE) < CAST('2019-05-02' AS DATE)) ;
to compare dates, I replace 2019-05*02 a formatted datetime object in php. Thnaks.

Comment: Please do not answer this way to the different question than the original one.

Comment: This does not answer the original question in any way

Answer (score 13):

You can use

```
select from_unixtime(1300464000,"%Y-%m-%d %h %i %s") from table;
```

Overall, there are two pertinent methods

1. from_unixtime()
2. unix_timestamp()

Comment: I would use this format for military time "%Y-%m-%d %H %i %s"

Comment: as @tannerburton says it's `H` not `h` as the OP wanted 24 hour time format

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT from_unixtime( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(fild_with_timestamp) ) from "your_table"`
This work for me