# Convert Unix timestamp into human readable date using MySQL

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

Is there a MySQL function which can be used to convert a Unix timestamp into a human readable date? I have one field where I save Unix times and now I want to add another field for human readable dates.

Comment: [Date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) in the mySQL manual

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert timestamp to datetime in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362874/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-datetime-in-mysql)

Answer (score 514, accepted):

Use [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,214465):

```
SELECT
  FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) 
FROM 
  your_table;
```

See also:  [MySQL documentation on `FROM_UNIXTIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).

Comment: Here's the official docs for `from_unixtime`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Comment: Sadly there's no `TO_UNIXTIME`, but instead `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: @OlleHärstedt it is sad indeed.

Comment: Won't that be `null` if the UNIX timestamp is above years 2038? At least, if you insert FROM_UNIXTIME({unix timestamp above 2039}) it will return null. It is a known issue.

Answer (score 147):

What's missing from the other answers (as of this writing) and not directly obvious is that [`from_unixtime`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) can take a second parameter to specify the format like so:

```
SELECT
  from_unixtime(timestamp, '%Y %D %M %H:%i:%s')
FROM 
  your_table
```

Comment: Very minor issue, but %h is hours in 12-hour format, which then requires %p for completeness (AM/PM). Or %H gives hours in 24-hour format.

Answer (score 33):

I think what you're looking for is [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Answer (score 25):

## Need a unix timestamp in a specific timezone?

Here's a one liner if you have quick access to the mysql cli:

```
mysql> select convert_tz(from_unixtime(1467095851), 'UTC', 'MST') as 'local time';

+---------------------+
| local time          |
+---------------------+
| 2016-06-27 23:37:31 |
+---------------------+
```

Replace `'MST'` with your desired timezone. I live in Arizona  thus the conversion from UTC to MST.

Answer (score 7):

Why bother saving the field as readable? Just us `AS`

```
SELECT theTimeStamp, FROM_UNIXTIME(theTimeStamp) AS readableDate
               FROM theTable
               WHERE theTable.theField = theValue;
```

EDIT: Sorry, we store everything in milliseconds not seconds. Fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the DATE_FORMAT function.  [Here](http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)'s a page with examples, and the patterns you can use to select different date components.

Answer (score 2):

Easy and simple way:

`select from_unixtime(column_name, '%Y-%m-%d') from table_name`

Answer (score 1):

Since I found this question not being aware, that mysql always stores time in timestamp fields in UTC but will display (e.g. phpmyadmin) in local time zone I would like to add my findings.

I have an automatically updated last_modified field, defined as:

```
`last_modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Looking at it with phpmyadmin, it looks like it is in local time, internally it is UTC

```
SET time_zone = '+04:00'; // or '+00:00' to display dates in UTC or 'UTC' if time zones are installed.
SELECT last_modified, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_modified), from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_modified), '%Y-%c-%d %H:%i:%s'), CONVERT_TZ(last_modified,@@session.time_zone,'+00:00') as UTC FROM `table_name`
```

In any constellation, UNIX_TIMESTAMP and 'as UTC' are always displayed in UTC time.

Run this twice, first without setting the time_zone.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to convert time AND display the data in a specific format you can use this string.

```
date_format(convert_tz(from_unixtime(TIMESTAMP), 'UTC', 'DESIRED TZ'), '%m/%d/%y')
```

where you add `convert_tz` to a date_format string. the `%m/%d/%y` being `month/day/year`.
you can find all the specific formats here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp