# Converting MySQL dates (from what I think are seconds)

Tags: mysql

I am pretty new to MySQL, and am looking at a table (through a query) that has three date fields.  However, they appear to be in seconds (but I could be wrong), but ultimately, I need to convert them to a valid date/time.

The numbers are:

```
1366272682
1366239600
1366272682
```

I think one of these dates is 18th April 2013.

Can someone let me know how I can convert them within the query (or indeed if I am right).

Thank you.

Comment: This is called unixtime and is the amount of seconds since jan 1st 1970. Unixtime is awesome :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Unix timestamp into human readable date using MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267564/convert-unix-timestamp-into-human-readable-date-using-mysql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those "numbers" are actually [Unix Timestamps](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php). Use [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to convert them into human friendly formats:

> Returns a representation of the unix_timestamp argument as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context.

For example:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1366272682, '%e%D %M %Y')
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you so much everyone for your help - it's all working.  PS - How useful is that......