# how to convert time to timezone specific time in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I have database that contains utc seconds. I need to write a mysql query for day wise filter, hour wise filter and weekend, weekday filter.

Comment: Provide any sample .. What is your input and output

Comment: Input like this "1451114203" and out would be any format of time like weekday or hour. I need to write a mysql query for day wise filters.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check this..

```
Date date = new Date(1451114203L);
            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
            String formatted = format.format(date);
            System.out.println(formatted);
```

with MYSQL

```
SELECT from_unixtime(1451114203) ;
SELECT from_unixtime(1451114203, '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s %a') ;
```

ref
[Convert Unix timestamp into human readable date using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267564/convert-unix-timestamp-into-human-readable-date-using-mysql)

Comment: this is java conversion. I need to convert that date on the fly in mysql query only.

Comment: there is no timezone specific conversions, i need to timezone specific weekday name like monday tuesday based on user current timezone.

Comment: Please refer api to make it timezone specific.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM tablename where FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME((1451114203)),'+05:30','-07:00')),'%W') = 'monday'

Here '+05:30' is the server timezone and '-07:00' is the user timezone. I am converting to user timezone. it will result weekday name of user specific timezone. It may be a long and lengthy process I am looking for better performance query.

above query will work with utcseconds only i am not guarantee for time stamps, I need to work on timestamp.