# Mysql Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value

Tags: mysql, datetime

```
mysql> describe taps;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| tag_id      | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| time_stamp  | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
| device_id   | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| device_type | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+

mysql> INSERT INTO `taps` (tag_id, time_stamp) VALUES(0, 1451610061);
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '1451610061' for column 'time_stamp' at row 1
```

WHY??  I have found many similar questions, but not of them seem quite this black and white.

`1451610061` ***is*** a valid timestamp. I checked it at http://www.unixtimestamp.com/ and it evaluates as expected.

So, why doesn't MySql like it?

Comment: why you use `1451610061` directly to your query? try to format it first as the field created already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MySQL `timestamp` format is `2016-02-13 15:48:29`   or `Y-m-d H:i:s`  convert your `timestamp` to that format first, and then MySQL will accept it.

If you insert a new record without defining the timestamp, and then select the row from that table, you will notice that that's the format that it gives to the new `default` record.

if if you want to convert it directly in your query use:

```
INSERT INTO `taps` (tag_id, time_stamp) VALUES(0, from_unixtime('1451610061'));
```

Using [this Q&A on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267564/convert-unix-timestamp-into-human-readable-date-using-mysql) as reference.
And [from_unixtime documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Comment: D;oh!  I had momentarily thought that it was an integer representing the number of seconds from the epoch. Very tired after a very long coding session. Thanks for being awake :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this ->

```
$item->time_stamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($request->time_stamp));
```