# PHP and MYSQL Find Records Based on Date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have been trying to pull records based on a specified date. In the DB I have a column where I store unix timestamps. The user has the option to select records based on a date. The user inputs: `08/08/2016` (for example)

How would I write my SQL statement to handle this?

```
$query .= "`".$o."` = '".date("Y-m-d",strtotime($v))."' AND ";
```

Here we see the line where part of the SQL statement is built, because more than one column could be targeted by the user during their search request.

Somehow I need to be able to turn `$o` (which is a column storing unix timestamps) into the Y-m-d format for comparison, as shown above and make this work in an SQL statement.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT

Here is what worked for me:

`$query .= "`".$o."`>= '".strtotime($v)."' AND`".$o."`< '".(strtotime($v)+(24*60*60))."' AND ";`

Comment: `$o` is a unix timestamp, or a column name?

Comment: $o is the name of the column.

Comment: You should reword you question then

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Question updated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Unix timestamp into human readable date using MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267564/convert-unix-timestamp-into-human-readable-date-using-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
"WHERE DATE(`$o`) = '".date("Y-m-d",strtotime($v))."'"
```

However this won't use indexes, so if you have a large table it will be slower. If you want to be able to use indexes you can do:

```
"WHERE `$o` >= ".date("Y-m-d",strtotime($v))."
  AND `$o` < ".date("Y-m-d",strtotime($v))." + INTERVAL 1 DAY"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this approach and use UNIX_TIMESTAMP on MySQL.

```
$v = '2016-08-04';
$query .= "'".$o."' = UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$v') AND ";
```