# How to get date from MySQL timestamp using PHP

Tags: mysql, timestamp

My timestamp in MySQL is `1571591400` and I want to get the date from this timestamp. I have tried a number of things but but nothing has worked.

```
"SELECT * FROM fixture_fixture WHERE from_unixtime(event_timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') = '$date'";
```

Comment: Already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267564/convert-unix-timestamp-into-human-readable-date-using-mysql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Unix timestamp into human readable date using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267564/convert-unix-timestamp-into-human-readable-date-using-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Below may help.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1571591400, '%D %M %Y');
o/p - '20th October 2019'
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1571591400) As 'String';
o/p - '2019-10-20 21:10:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want date from you timestamp then you should trythis

```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(column_name), '%e %b %Y') AS 'date_formatted' FROM `fixture_fixture `
```