# Converting Unix Timestamp to MySQL DATETIME

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

This sounds silly but for the life of me I cannot figure it out. I have tried everything.

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to get my date string into my MySQL table... I've been converting to Unix first to account for variations in input format..

`$_POST['date']` is in this format:19-1-2013 4:43:32

```
$datestr= strtotime($_POST['date']);
    echo $datestr;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `calendar` (`date`, `title`, `event`) VALUES ('FROM_UNIXTIME(".$datestr.")', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['desc'])."')";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
```

This is the most recent thing I've tried and I'm still getting all zeros in my DATETIME field.

Please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert timestamp to datetime in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362874/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-datetime-in-mysql)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

remove single quotes aroung the function `FROM_UNIXTIME` because it will make it a value. eg

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `calendar` (`date`, `title`, `event`) VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME(".$datestr."), '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['desc'])."')";
```

As a sidenote, your query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`, please see the article below to learn how to protect from it

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)