# Insert current time to MySQL table using CDbMigration

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, yii, timestamp

How should I use MySQL's `FROM UNIXTIME` correctly in [`CDbMigration`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbMigration/) in Yii 1.x?

I have *borrowed* solution of converting current time given as timestamp, to MySQL's `DateTime` field from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14212211/1469208) and when just printing it:

```
echo 'FROM_UNIXTIME('.$base.')'."\n";
echo 'FROM_UNIXTIME('.$sixDaysLater.')'."\n";
```

everything seems fine:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(1418223600)
FROM_UNIXTIME(1418742000)
```

But, when I'm trying to use the same technique as a part of my migration:

```
$this->insert('contents', array
(
    'author_id'=>1,
    'type'=>5,
    'status'=>1,
    'category'=>1,
    'title'=>'title',
    'body'=>'body',
    'creation_date'=>'FROM_UNIXTIME('.$base.')',
    'modification_date'=>'FROM_UNIXTIME('.$base.')',
    'availability_date'=>'FROM_UNIXTIME('.$sixDaysLater.')',
    'short'=>'short'
));
```

This fails -- that is, migration goes fine, but I can see in phpMyAdmin, that related fields for this record has been populated with zeros (`0000-00-00 00:00:00`), not with the expected value.

What am I missing? Is it, because values in `insert` are being encoded / escaped?

Comment: all-zeroes dates means that you tried to insert an invalid date string. have you checked what the `$base` value is at the times you get those invalid dates?

Comment: Yes, as you can see above (first example), the values are correct timestamp. Basing on answer below and my own second thought, I assume, that the problem is because entire value is escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**CDBExpression**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbExpression) instead:

```
new CDbExpression("NOW()");
```

I mean:

```
'creation_date'=>new CDbExpression("NOW()")
```

Or if you want to use `FROM UNIXTIME` you can do the same.

> **CDbExpression** represents a DB expression that does not need escaping.

Comment: Damn, I keep forgeting about, how useful `CDbExpression` is! :| Thanks, anyway...