# CONVERT or CAST field in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, casting

I have a TimeStamp field in a MySQL database that I'm trying to pull data from. I'm trying to get it as a string, so I've been using the following query:

`select CONVERT(VARCHAR, date_created, 120) from junk;`

It throws the error:

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR, date_modified, 120) from junk limit 10' at line 1`

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: MySql and Sql Server are two completley different products. The error message you are using MySql, _not_ Sql Server.

Comment: Pretty sure that `CONVERT` is not-ANSI standard and is specific to SQL Server. `CAST` is standard but I don't believe allows formatting codes.

Comment: VarChar needs a size e.g. VarChar(10)

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Actually in SQL Server `varchar` without sizing gets an implicit size of something like 30. Still, the problem is in mixing T-SQL code with MySQL RDBMS.

Comment: Aye saw the convert and style immediately put my sql server head on for some reason...

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying that. Bigger question is, how do I go about converting it into a String as I'm pulling it from the DB?

Comment: Hmmm, normally I wouldn't convert a date to a string when pulling from the db. I'd get the date and then let my app deal with formatting as and when.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson the issue with that is that I'm pulling into Pentaho which is using JDBC and there are quite a lot of NULL TimeStamps (For some odd reason), and I'm to leave them as it is and not assign a 'fake' value to fix the data. The easiest way to handle it would be to convert it to a string and just leave it as it is, as far as I can see. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Well if Pentaho can't deal with nulls, that would be an exeception to my 'Normally I wouldn't do that rule. :(

Comment: @TonyHopkinson it seems to be a [JDBC thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696902/jdbc-converting-timestamp-to-null-zerodatetimebehavior-issue/22700917?noredirect=1#22700917).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to format explicitly to yyyymmdd (style 120 in sql server)

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(somedate, '%Y%m%d') From SomeTable
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The format isn't what I was looking for, but I changed that around to get what I needed. I used the following code: `select DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') from junk;`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`CONVERT()` in `MySQL` is used to convert between different character sets, you need `DATE_FORMAT()`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%Y%m%d %H%i%S')
FROM Junk
```

Update:  Originally had `CAST()` incorrectly using `VARCHAR()`, but `CAST()` will also work:

```
SELECT CAST(date_created AS CHAR(10))
FROM Junk
```

[DATE_FORMAT() options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: `mysql> select CAST(date_created AS VARCHAR(30)) from junk;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(30)) from junk' at line 1`

Any more suggestions?

Comment: `CAST()` should work as well - but `DATE_FORMAT()` is indeed preferable.

Comment: @ypercube Why did `CAST()` give him an error?  I'm a SQL Server guy, still plenty to learn about MySQL.

Comment: Ah, it should be `CAST(date_created AS CHAR(30))` or better: `CAST(date_created AS CHAR(10))`

Answer (score 0):

In MySql, the [`CONVERT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html) function is used to convert existing string types (like varchar) between character sets (like utf-8 or ascii). To format a TimeStamp column, use the [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function.

Comment: `FROM_UNIXTIME` converts all the data in that column to `NULL`.

`select FROM_UNIXTIME(date_created) from junk;` is the query I used.