# Mysql convert integer to date

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a database that stores dates and time as integers on a database column `idate`, I would like to show the actual dates using a command but I need assistance.

Here's how the table looks like:

```
id  user_id amount  idate   status  
1   23  1000    60  1493723513  NULL
2   23  1000    60  1493724293  NULL
3   19  9000    120 1491239643  finished
4   19  9000    120 1493831643  NULL
5   27  1531.8  360 1493920525  ongoing
6   20  5618    30  1493832270  finished
7   20  4215    30  1494231929  finished
8   35  1000    60  1494325129  NULL
9   35  2000    90  1494325335  NULL
10  11  5000    90  1495364902  ongoing
```

Using the first `id` column I want to view the date of `1493723513` in format *`2017-12-08 17:11:43`*.

SOLUTION : I used "

```
SELECT `id`, `user_id`, `amount`, `status`, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`idate`), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS `date` FROM `tablename`
```

QUESTION: How can i edit the date and time to a different date as desired, date is stored as e.g "1493723513" on idate, how can i edit both date and timestap from this integer.

Comment: Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert timestamp to datetime in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362874/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-datetime-in-mysql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query will output formatted date from record timestamp in required format.

```sql
SELECT `id`, `user_id`, `amount`, `status`, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`idate`), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS `date` FROM `tablename`
```

- **[`FROM_UNIXTIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)** and **[`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)** do all the magic.

> As *[@BillKarwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732907/mysql-convert-integer-to-date#comment82426625_47732907)* mentioned [**this MySQL ref page**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) can be useful.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, it worked. FROM_UNIXTIME and DATE_FORMAT really did the magic.

Comment: Hello @Paul T. Rawkeen How can i edit the output easily to any desired date or time, i am trying to edit from the output but it won't let me, on column date is stored as e.g "1493723513" how can i edit this to a desired date,  kindly assist me

Comment: @Kingx try reading **[`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)**.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thank you for your reply, i have read the article but i am still having some problems, kindly help me solve this with your own example command to edit the dates on the column "idate".