# Change date format when adding where condition to the query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Database:

```
   | date_paid (int) |
    1535558400
    1539532800
```

I am trying to query the following but i get SQL syntax error for the date part.

```
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $date = $this->input->post('date');

    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $this->db->where('DATE_FORMAT(date_paid, "%Y-%m-%d")',$date);
    $query=$this->db->get('payments');
    $result=$query->row();
```

Is there any way to change the date format of the column `date_paid` so that i can actually compare it to the `$this->input->post('date')` data?

Error log:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2018-10-30'' at line 4
```

I am trying to modify an existing web application that is why as much as possible i do not want to change the data type of the column `date_paid`

thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us the error message IN FULL

Comment: Also what datatype is the `date_paid` column please

Comment: Also what format is the `date` you get from the post array

Comment: please see edited post

Comment: I have no suggested changing the datatype I just wanted to knwo what it was

Comment: And the format of the input date from the user is also very relevant

Comment: which format do you want to get?

Comment: i want to achieve this format Y-m-d

Comment: Show us which formats the user could enter the date in. One would hope only one format, but you cannot match a date to the date on the database unless you know what format the incoming date could be in

Comment: the post('date') is actually `type='hidden'`. i am passing a string with this format `Y-m-d`

Answer (score 0):

Please, use like this

```
 DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_paid`), '%Y-%m-%d') AS 'date_changed'
```

You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732907/mysql-convert-integer-to-date)

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (payments) WHERE id = '28' AND date_formated = '2018-10-30' at line 2

Comment: Did you refer my given link?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_paid`), '%Y-%m-%d') AS 'date_formatted'

so something like:

```
$id = $this->input->post('id');
$date = $this->input->post('date');

$this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_paid`), '%Y-%m-%d') AS date_formatted");
$this->db->from('payments');
$this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_paid`), '%Y-%m-%d') = " . $date, '', false);

$result = $q->row();
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (`payments`) WHERE `id` = '28' AND `date_formated` = '2018-10-30' at line 2

Comment: @RonaldTorres Updated the query.

Answer (score -2):

Use the syntax below

select convert(varchar(4), year(ColumnDate))+'/'+convert(varchar(4), month(ColumnDate))+'/'+convert(varchar(4), day(ColumnDate)) from YourTable