# Convert time() from SQL for monthly sales PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to make monthly sales from the **sales** table but i store date data using **time()** format

Example :

```
UserID | Product | Date
1      | Hot Dog | 1504363230
4      | Chicken | 1504695631
1      | Potato  | 1504761716
3      | Spinach | 1505003789
```

So, how can i create monthly sales from there without replace Date into **date()** ? Because it will take a long time if i have to change 300K row

What should i do ?

> Select * FROM Sales WHERE UserID = UserID AND Date = ?

the output must be like this

> UserID 1 do 2 transaction in the last month   or  UserID 1 do 3 transaction in this
>   month

Comment: You can convert it on MySQL it self, and filtering on the same way, it will be faster that make it on another way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert timestamp to datetime in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362874/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-datetime-in-mysql)

Comment: Looks like you have tons of good answers. On a related note, consider storing your time stamp as a `DATETIME` instead. It's readable as a string and you can still do math. You also won't run into the max integer size problem

Comment: @devlincarnate sorry, I do not mean that

Answer (score 0):

A PHP solution would be to use the second parameter in the [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function:

```
string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
```

> The optional timestamp parameter is an integer Unix timestamp that defaults to the current local time if a timestamp is not given. In other words, it defaults to the value of time().

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i don't mean so. Sorry, I've edited the post more clearly

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
I think this should work for you. I guess you want to avoid PHP's `date()` but MySQL's `DATE()` is okay.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS nb_transaction,
    UserID
FROM
    sales
WHERE
    DATE(`Date`) LIKE '2018-06-%'
```

Of course replace the month with the one you are looking for.

---

**SQL (will be faster than PHP):**
You can convert any [UNIX Timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) using [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to any format:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(`Date`, '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s')
```

---

**PHP:**
The [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function returns a [UNIX Timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

If you want to display a date using one, you can use [`DateTime::setTimestamp`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php):

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp($row['Date']);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');    // Hot Dog = 2017-09-02 14:40:30
```

Or shortly:

```
echo (new DateTime())->setTimestamp($row['Date'])->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i don't mean so. Sorry, I've edited the post more clearly

Comment: Hi @Zeeeeth, I updated my answer. Tell me if this isn't what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a unix timestamp to a datetime string in MySQL with FROM_UNIXTIME.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(`Date`) as `Datetime` FROM sales
```

You can then expand on this with other date functions like MONTH or YEAR

```
SELECT MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`Date`)) as `Month` FROM sales
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i don't mean so. Sorry, I've edited the post more clearly

Answer (score -1):

```
$timestamp = 1517317337107; $date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',
   $timestamp/1000); 
 echo "date and time : ". $date."<br>";
   $month=date('Y-m-d',$timestamp/1000);
 echo "only date : ".$month."<br>";


#output
date and time : 2018-01-30 13:02:17
only date : 2018-01-30
```

hope this will help

Comment: I don't like to downvote, but a solution with date was already posted and your dividing by 1000 would result in an invalid result based on the OP's inputs.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i don't mean so. Sorry, I've edited the post more clearly